# How to reverse an oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have following query which returns all the managers of a company

```
Select emp_id 
from Managers 
where ... some more conditions
```

Now, if I want to get the manager of managers (senior manager), I will have to write the following query:

```
select emp_id 
from Managers 
where emp_number = (Select emp_id 
                    from Managers)
```

This will return something like:

```
Manager   Senior manager
0001      1111
0002      1111
0003      1111
0004      2222
0005      2222
```

As per the above record, a senior manager can contain many managers. I want to fetch all the managers  under '1111'. In short I want to reverse the above query. I tried many approaches but they seem to be very lengthy. (Above query is just an ex. Real query is much bigger)

Can anyone suggest an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a `CONNECT BY` query:

```
    SELECT emp_id
      FROM managers
START WITH emp_id = '1111'
CONNECT BY emp_id = PRIOR emp_number;
```

Based on your example, it sounds as though the column *emp_id* is the primary key for an employee and *emp_number* is a self referential foreign key to the manager of an employee, allowing you to build a hierarchy from this one table. To make your example more clear, it seems as though *emp_number* should be named *manager_id*:

```
-- Will show you all of the hierarchy ABOVE emp_id 1111
    SELECT emp_id
      FROM managers
START WITH emp_id = '1111'
CONNECT BY emp_id = PRIOR manager_id;
```

Another example of using a `CONNECT BY` would be to find all the children that roll up to a parent within a hierarchy:

```
-- Will show you all of the hierarchy BELOW emp_id 1111
    SELECT emp_id
      FROM managers
START WITH emp_id = '1111'
CONNECT BY manager_id = PRIOR emp_id;
```